# First connect to Glassfish v3 is slow

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, glassfish, ejb-3.0, ejb

When trying to connect to glassfish v3 from swing application it is very slow for the first time. Takes 4-10 seconds. 
On the client side:

```
public void myMethod(){
    NewSessionBeanRemote facade;
    try {
        InitialContext ic = new InitialContext();
        facade = (NewSessionBeanRemote) ic.lookup(NewSessionBeanRemote.class.getName());
        target.setText(facade.businessMethod());
    } catch (NamingException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

On the server side:

```
@Stateless
public class NewSessionBean implements NewSessionBeanRemote {

    @Override
    public String businessMethod() {
        return String.valueOf(Math.random() + 121 + 300);
    }
}

@Remote
public interface NewSessionBeanRemote {

    String businessMethod();

}
```

What do I need to change in the environment?

Comment: I havn't used Glassfish before, but could this just be the standard Java Virtual Machine cold start?

Comment: The server is running. All other times i get the data momently.

Answer (score 0):

> When trying to connect to glassfish v3 from swing application it is very slow for the first time.

Might be due to the [lazy initialization of Application Server services](http://weblogs.java.net/blog/binod/archive/2005/09/lazy_initializa.html) (EJB Container, Connection pool,...).

> Takes 4-10 seconds.

What about subsequent calls?

Comment: subsequent calls are 30 milliseconds

Comment: How can I turn the lazy initialization off?

Answer (score 0):

This is how Java EE works. When a page is called for the first time all JSPs are compiled and all beans instantiated. Even if you turn off lazy initialization, you will have to wait the same amount of time on startup.

Citation from wikipedia.org https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaServer_Pages#Compiler

> A JavaServer Pages compiler is a program that parses JSPs, and
>   transforms them into executable Java Servlets. A program of this type
>   is usually embedded into the application server and run automatically
>   the first time a JSP is accessed, but pages may also be precompiled
>   for better performance, or compiled as a part of the build process to
>   test for errors.

If you want, you can try to pre-compile everything and see if it works better:

http://www.avajava.com/tutorials/lessons/how-do-i-precompile-my-jsps.html